# Total RecordCount as OUTPUT of Paged Result Set in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, records, rowcount

i have a question on stored procedures.

I try to get a page of result set and the record count of the whole set.

Each of this is working on it's own, but I'm unable to combine it:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.pagingSCP
@PageStart INT, 
@PageSize INT, 
@RecordCount INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
WITH AllRecords AS ( 
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MATNR) 
AS Row, viewStyleColorInModul.*
FROM viewStyleColorInModul WHERE SPRAS = 'D'
) SELECT * FROM AllRecords WHERE Row between 
@PageStart and @PageStart + @PageSize
END
```

(50 row(s) returned)
@RecordCount = 0
@RETURN_VALUE = 0
Finished running [dbo].[pagingSCP].

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.pagingSCP
@PageStart INT, 
@PageSize INT, 
@RecordCount INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
WITH AllRecords AS ( 
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MATNR) 
AS Row, viewStyleColorInModul.*
FROM viewStyleColorInModul WHERE SPRAS = 'D'
) SELECT @RecordCount = Count(*) From AllRecords
END
```

No rows affected.
(0 row(s) returned)
@RecordCount = 43770
@RETURN_VALUE = 0
Finished running [dbo].[pagingSCP].

**Is is now somehow possible to get the 50 Rows and the total Recordcount
within the single query?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.pagingSCP
@PageStart INT, 
@PageSize INT, 
@RecordCount INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
  -- get record count
  WITH AllRecords AS ( 
    SELECT viewStyleColorInModul.*
  FROM viewStyleColorInModul WHERE SPRAS = 'D'
  ) SELECT @RecordCount = Count(*) From AllRecords;

  -- now get the records
  WITH AllRecords AS ( 
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MATNR) 
   AS Row, viewStyleColorInModul.*
   FROM viewStyleColorInModul WHERE SPRAS = 'D'
  ) SELECT * FROM AllRecords 
  WHERE Row between @PageStart and @PageStart + @PageSize;
END
```

You have two distinct queries, therefor eyou run two distinct SELECT and let the SQL optimizer optimize each individually. Even if trying to get both queries in one SELECT *is* possible, is highly counterproductive and sub-optimal.

As a side note, in the client code any output parameter is available only **after** iterating all results returned.

Comment: this is exactly what we thought, too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the guts of a paging proc we used all the time. It works by first dumping all the matching records into a temp table (WHERE SPRAS = 'D').

It then selects from the temp table, only the records from page X of Y. It also includes the total records of the original selection (WHERE SPRAS = 'D').

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spSelectTempUsers] 

@Page       int = 0,
@NumPerPage int = 1

AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

CREATE TABLE #TempData 
(
[RowId]     [int] identity(1,1) ,
[UserId]    [int]               ,
[FirstName] [varchar](50)       ,
[LastName]  [varchar](50)       ,
[Email]     [varchar](255)      ,
[SPRAS]     [varchar](36)
)

INSERT INTO #TempData 
(
[UserId]    ,
[FirstName] ,
[LastName]  ,
[Email]     ,
[SPRAS]      
)

SELECT
[UserId]    ,
[FirstName] ,
[LastName]  ,
[Email]     ,
[SPRAS]      

FROM viewStyleColorInModul
WHERE [SPRAS] = 'D'


DECLARE @Count int
DECLARE @Pages int
DECLARE @i     int
DECLARE @j     int

IF @Page < 1 SET @Page = 1
SET @Count = (SELECT COUNT(RowId) FROM #TempData)
SET @Pages = @Count / @NumPerPage
IF (@Pages * @NumPerPage) < @Count SET @Pages = @Pages + 1
IF @Page > @Pages SET @Page = @Pages
SET @i = ((@Page -1) * @NumPerPage) +1
SET @j = @Page * @NumPerPage

SELECT 

ISNULL(t1.UserId,'')    as UserId,
ISNULL(t1.FirstName,'') as FirstName   ,
ISNULL(t1.LastName,'')  as LastName       ,
ISNULL(t1.Email,'')     as Email      ,
ISNULL(t1.SPRAS,'')     as SPRAS,

@Pages as Pages,
@Count as TotalRecords

FROM #TempData t1


WHERE   t1.RowId >= @i AND t1.RowId <= @j

ORDER BY t1.RowId

DROP TABLE #TempData
SET NOCOUNT OFF
```